# repeat text in script

Tags: text, repeat

i have file which contains text like

```
    Host:xxx.xxx.xxx.123
    Host:xxx.xxx.xxx.124
    Host:xxx.xxx.xxx.125
```

Questin is how to get this file like (unix way)

```
    Host:xxx.xxx.xxx.123; something xxx.xxx.xxx.123
    Host:xxx.xxx.xxx.124; something xxx.xxx.xxx.124
    Host:xxx.xxx.xxx.125; something xxx.xxx.xxx.125
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an awk alternative:

awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{ printf "%s:%s;  Something %s \n", $1, $2, $2 }' yourfile.txt

awk is great for line by line string manipulation like this. Just direct the output to a destination file if you want.
if it doesn't quite get it, check out an AWK tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

awk might also be used but this works (file1 is your original file):

```
cut -d":" file1 -f2 > tmp.txt; paste tmp.txt tmp.txt | \
sed 's/^/Host:/' | sed 's/\s/; something /'
```

It's not very refined, and most people wouldn't use sed twice, but it works.  To spew it to a file just end it with > file2